# PC to PC file transfer using FireWire

Tags: windows-7, firewire

Is there a way to copy transfer files over FireWire from one laptop to another? Both have windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you'll need to get [ubCore](http://www.unibrain.com/products/driverapi/ubcore.htm) since Microsoft didn't put FireWire networking in Windows 7.